# Query Elastic Search for a list

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to emulate the working of IN operator. The query which I am trying and not working is :
This below query is giving 0 records.

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "ch" : ["X", "Y", "Z"]
    }
  }}},
  "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "ch",
            "orgnm"
        ],
        "excludes": []
    }
}
```

So, basically I am trying to do

```
select ch, orgnm from index_name where ch in ('X', Y', 'Z');
```

Comment: I guess _ch_ is analyzed by default and hence you would have to use lowercase letters. Try with ["x","y","z"]

Comment: Yea. I just figured it out. Btw thanks!